# troubles with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a NSString: `@"05.03.2013, 21:33"`
I want to get NSDate from this string

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy',' hh:mm"];
NSDate *discussionDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:discModel.date];
```

After that i put NSLog and it prints than `discussionDate` is `nil`

Comment: What steps have you taken to try to solve this yourself?

Comment: Have you checked that discModel.date is not nil?

Comment: discModel.date is NSString: @"05.03.2013, 21:33"

Comment: i have tried different NSDateFormatter and no one works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                            [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy',' HH:mm"];
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but date in string and date in NSDate differs in 4 hours. May be, this connected with UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `HH` instead of `hh` for your time format

and it is good idea to set the timeZone also for avoiding the time changes

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CET"]];
```